# android open pdf from internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a pdf in the app's internal storage, however, I cannot open the file in the system pdf app.

```
val pdfDirPath = File(context.filesDir, "pdfs")
val file: File = File(pdfDirPath, "title.pdf")
val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

it shows the error "cannot display pdf"

Comment: Other apps cannot access your app's internal storage, and `Uri.fromFile()` has not worked for much in the past six years. Use `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
is that right ?

Comment: Replace with files-path